# Using custom post types to give Wordpress a more CMS-like look. What to prioritaize? Pages or Content?

Tags: custom-post-types

I've been adding custom post types in the admin panel and endingup with the following results:

**1. Prioritazing content:**

Posts (blog entries, news, events...)

Pages

Static Content (custom post type) -> Sections (custom taxonomy) (Tagline, Slider, 
Mainbar...)
...

In this case, I divided the pages into sections, the problem is that the client can only know where the section is by creating a term like this: Tagline (Front-Page).

**2. Prioritizing pages:**

Pages

Front-Page (custom post type) -> Sections (custom post type) (Tagline, Slider, Mainbar...)

News (custom post type) ...

Events (custom post type) ...

Photos (custom post type) ...

About (custom post type) ...

Blog (custom post type) ...

Contact (custom post type) ...

In this case, the client will know to which page the content will go. But if the user will see some pages he or she may never use.

Which method is more efficient concerning content managment?

Do you have another better alternative?

**Reference Picture of case #1 (the custom post type is called Static Content and the custom taxonomy is called Sections. Posts will be preserved but used in Categories called Events, News, etc...):*.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@janoChen:**

Definitely #1.  #2 will create a lot of complexity for the user.

To address the problems you've identified with #1 I would recommend removing the static content post types from the admin and isntead creating a custom admin page that allows the user to add static sections via AJAX with links to their edit pages.

Comment: Yeah you answer did help me. Please can you give me a little bit more details about 'creating a custom admin page that allows the user to add static sections via AJAX with links to their edit pages' (if there's no Static Content menu in which other ways the user can create the content)?

Comment: @janoChen - I don't fully understand your use case yet. Do you have screenshots that can illustrate? And in your model is there one *"Tagline (Front Page)"* or many, and if many where are the different ones used and how does the client specify?

Comment: Only one 'Tagline (Front Page)' term. For 'Slider (Front Page)' also only one. There's also a term for instance, called Work (Portfolio). Basically, there's only one term which delivers the content to an specific page and the parenthesis shows which page (I know is not the right way but it is a temporally solution). I added an image in EDIT.

Comment: @janoChen - Okay, if the static content is going to be specific to a page, why not have then just edit that content in a custom field on the specific page that it's associated with. Unless I misunderstand it seems you are trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be?